# Printing a 2D Array Combinations Without Duplicates

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm struggling to print unique combinations to a 2D array that hold the same value.

Example 2D Array

[4, 4, 4, 4]

[4, 4, 4, 4]

Possible Unique Combinations

0,1

0,2

0,3

1,2

1,3

Could anyone give pointers on how to tackle this?

Comment: Use two for loops with == comparison.

Comment: Possible unique combinations? There are no unique combinations at all in your example, at least none that I could see.

Comment: @LordAnomander unique combinations as in 0, 1 and 1,0 don't repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this by looping through the array correctly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < array.length[i]; j++) {
        // as you start with j = i+1 you will avoid comparing the same cells
    }
}
```